# Change display of list element, its child and move element up the list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hava a list with the list elements styled as inline-block. When each list element is clicked I want to:

1. change display:inline-block; to display:block; of list element,
2. change display: none; to display: block; of child div
3. Move the clicked element to top of list
4. If more than one element is clicked, all of them do the same and move up the list together.

When clicked again (toggle), I want the list to reverse the above (reverse displays and return to its original position).

So far, I have only managed to change the display of the list element to block, but I can't target the child div with element.children, or move the list element up to the top.

```js
function showCombo(ID) {
  var x = document.getElementById(ID);
  var xshow = getComputedStyle(x, null).display; //

  if (xshow == "inline-block") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li ID="1" onclick="showCombo(1)">
    <p>Title 1</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li ID="2" onclick="showCombo(2)">
    <p>Title 2</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li ID="3" onclick="showCombo(3)">
    <p>Title 3</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li ID="4" onclick="showCombo(4)">
    <p>Title 4</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li ID="5" onclick="showCombo(5)">
    <p>Title 5</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggle a class with all the properties and it would be easier:

```js
function showCombo(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li div {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  list-style:none;
}
li.active {
   width:100%; /* full width*/
   order:-1; /* move to the top */
}
li.active div {
  display:block; /* show div */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="showCombo(this)">
    <p>Title 1</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li onclick="showCombo(this)">
    <p>Title 2</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li  onclick="showCombo(this)">
    <p>Title 3</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li  onclick="showCombo(this)">
    <p>Title 4</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li onclick="showCombo(this)">
    <p>Title 5</p>
    <div>Show content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's impressively simple. Would it complicate things if the first list element opens in its own place without moving to the top, but if two or more are clicked they both move to the top?

Comment: @suverenia yes it would make the script a bit complex. I may need to add more JS to handle this

Comment: Ok, I'm quite satisfied with this anyway! Is it possible to close and open all easily?

Comment: @suverenia yes, you can move the `active` class to the ul and toggle it there and change the CSS a little to target like `ul.active li`

Comment: Okay thank you. This is causing me trouble, though, as the child div contains links and pictures and input fields, which cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

I created Your idea using javascript with great focus on it, but you can use `order` in css like the previous answer it will be more easier, if you have a question ask me, and if you want a small edit tell me, I will put the explanation links of some events, functions that I used them in my javascript code in case you don't know them

[insertBefore](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp)

[prepend](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prepend.asp#:%7E:text=The%20prepend()%20method%20inserts,use%20the%20append()%20method.)

[classlist](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

[getElementsByClassName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

[getAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp)

[setAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

```js
var li = document.getElementsByClassName("li"),
    ul = document.getElementById("ul");

for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i = i + 1) {
  
  li[i].setAttribute("index", i); // Create attribute named index and its value will be the i, this is to know the index of the li, we need it when clicked on it again
  
  li[i].setAttribute("firstclick", "yes"); // This is to know if we clicked at it firsttime or secondtime toggle
  
  li[i].onclick = function () {
   
    if (this.getAttribute("firstclick") == "yes") {
      this.setAttribute("firstclick", "no"); // Change it to no to when clicking it once again read the second case
      
       ul.prepend(this); // Put the clicked li at the top of the li, prepend means to put it the first element
      this.classList.add("displayBlock") // add the class displayBlock check it in the css it contains display: block
            this.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].classList.add("displayBlock"); // Add the displayBlock to the div inside the clicked li to show
    } else {
      this.setAttribute("firstclick", "yes"); // Change it to yes to when clicking it once again read the first case
      
      ul.insertBefore(this, li[parseInt(this.getAttribute("index")) + 1]) // Insert It to its original position
      
     this.classList.remove("displayBlock"); // Remove the display block class
      this.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].classList.remove("displayBlock"); // Remove the display block class
      
      
    }
    
    
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li div {
  display: none;
}

.displayBlock {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
 <li class="li" >
    <p>Title 1</p>
    <div class="content">Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li class="li" >
      <p>Title 2</p>
      <div class="content">Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li class="li" >
      <p>Title 3</p>
      <div class="content">Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li class="li" >
      <p>Title 4</p>
      <div class="content">Show content</div>
  </li>
  <li class="li" >
      <p>Title 5</p>
      <div class="content">Show content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Taha. Thank you. Your script has several problems. 1) if you expand all you will have erratic behaviour messing with the margin in between the elements, but also their position and order. 2) In some instances, some of the list elements are not moved up, and list elements are stuck above and below. 3) div cannot contain div input field.

Comment: Hello, for point 1 you can edit the css like adding margin and this is not our focus right now, for the other points yes you are right, I can solve it but just use the order in css like the previous answer and it will be better and more simple because I will write many new lines in javascript (the code will be big more :) ). The most important thing that is your idea solved, and I make a try to solve it. Have a nice day :), if you have any question just ask